# How to remove the flavor name (prod/dev) from Flutter app's versionName: 1.0.0-prod?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, apk, google-play-console

I have an app developed with Flutter, I have the following line in my `pubspec.yaml` file:

`version: 1.0.0+1`

But when I generate an apk - the versionName becomes 1.0.0-prod.
I uploaded the app to Google Play and the suffix is present there too.

Is there a way to remove the flavor name from the versionName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app/build.gradle` remove  `versionNameSuffix ".prod"` and `applicationIdSuffix ".prod"`

Current code might look something like this

```
productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "counterapp"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Counter App Dev"
            versionNameSuffix ".dev"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "counterapp"
            applicationIdSuffix ".prod"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Counter App Prod"
            versionNameSuffix ".prod"
        }
    }
}
```

Updated code

```
productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "counterapp"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Counter App Dev"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "counterapp"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Counter App Prod"
        }
    }
}
```